# How to delete string after some charecters in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I have a string `/uploads/images/mypic_123.png` now i want to get only image name like `mypic_123.png`.Please tell me how to do it? I am using objective-c.

Comment: [string lastPathComponent].

Comment: Your strings seem to be paths. Maybe you can reflect that in the question and its title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSString has a method named [lastPathComponent](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/lastPathComponent) that you can use

Answer (score 2):

you can use this way:-

```
 NSURL *url;
 NSString *substring=[url lastPathComponent];
 NSLog(@"Your image name is :%@",substring);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the below code

```
NSString *str = @"/uploads/images/mypic_123.png";
NSArray *parts = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *filename = [parts lastObject];
```

Comment: I don't think this works with paths that end with a `/`.